# User Registration setting missing in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system, joomla3.0

This is my first experience in Joomla V3.3.6

I have a requirement where there would be 2 user types.

```
-> User Type 1
-> User Type 2
```

1) I am looking out for registration module in Joomla. Searched and looks there are lots of plugins. But also understood that Joomla by default has default Registration module as per the below link:

- http://docs.joomla.org/Allowing_user_registration
- http://docs.joomla.org/Setting_user_registration_policy

The issue is, I do not see a place in **Global Settings** where there is **User Settings** as defined by the above link. Hence not able to see the registration page.

2) I see in admin dashboard, **User Manager**, **User Groups**. I guess, I could use these user groups to define the User Types. Please confirm if this is how it is in Joomla?

Kindly Help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the administrator, go to **User Manager**
At the top right, you'll see **Options**
That's where you set the user/registration options